# Error when checking input: expected acc_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (200, 3, 1)

Tags: arrays, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer, keras-2

I have tried many times and read the answer to the question similar to me, but still did not solve.

Error when checking input: expected acc_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (200, 3, 1)

```
model.fit(x=[acc_,gyro_],y=[scaled_labels],batch_size=1,validation_split=0.2, epochs=2,verbose=1,shuffle=False)
```

The first layer of my network is the Input layer

```
acc_input_tensor = Input(shape=(200,3,1),name = 'acc_input')
gyro_input_tensor = Input(shape=(200,3,1),name= 'gyro_input')
```

The input is the acceleration and gyroscope data. 200 refers to 200 sets of data, 3 refers to the acceleration of the measured value of x,y,z. I put the acceleration data and gyro data reshape into (200 * 3 * 1)

```
acc_ = np.reshape(acc,(200,3,1))
gyro_ = np.reshape(gyro,(200,3,1))
```

The input is three-dimensional data, the given data input is three-dimensional, why there are four-dimensional requirements? How to modify it?

[This is the model I created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkGop.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what type of network your using, but `input_shape` does not include length of data. it should just be this

```
acc_input_tensor = Input(shape=(3,1),name = 'acc_input')
gyro_input_tensor = Input(shape=(3,1),name= 'gyro_input')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer！I use the acceleration data in one cycle as input（200*3），acc_input_tensor = Input(shape=(200,3),name = 'acc_input')
gyro_input_tensor = Input(shape=(200,3),name= 'gyro_input')  This is still a mistake to modify

Comment: I'm talking (200 * 3) reshape into (20 * 30*1) into the convolution layer，Convolution layers require three-dimensional data

Comment: The input shape to convolution depends on they type of convolution layer your using, but in any event `shape=()` doesn't not take the size of the first dimension, only the second,third,fourth... and so on.